# What do we call an object that is going to be, or is being, or has been consolidated?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, nouns, word-usage

What do we call an object that is a member in the action of consolidation?

Is "consolidatee" a word?

For example, I have two sets of objects that are going to be consolidated into one single set of objects. Is there a noun for the objects that are being / are about to be / have already been consolidated?

Could I say:

> I put the contents of the boxes together, they were consolidatees in the process of combining them?

Like, for instance, the word employ. Where to employ somebody they are an employee, who has been employed by an employer --> if we are to consolidate, then has the consolidator consolidated a consolidatee?

If not, then what is the word I am looking for, and what do we call this type of word in English?

It's a noun of consolidate I guess, but I feel as though it may have a more specific categorization.

Please forgive me, I have absolutely zero understanding of the formalities of English (or any natural language), I'm a software engineering/AI guy, my language specialties are not natural but rather constructed/artificial.

Comment: The word "aggregation" may correspond. Depending on the context, it means either the action of collecting objects into a whole or its result.

Comment: "collection", "combination".

Comment: These don't get at what I am asking, aggregation and collection/combination are referring to the entire group of objects that have been consolidated. I am after the word for one of the individual objects that are undergoing that process of being consolidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constituents

You could say constituents - these are the parts that make up a whole.

And in your example:

I put the items in the two boxes together, they were constituents in the process of being combined (to form a single, new collection of objects.)

The consolidator has consolidated constituents.

Your problem, I think is that the idea of 'a consolidate' - an item that is being consolidated either doesn't exist or is not commonly used. Whereas for example, you can say  'a constituent' or 'an aggregate'.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/constituent

Comment: You could also use components, elements, parts, sections, subcomponents, or many other synonyms, but constituents is good.

Comment: Yes, I considered those, Stuart, along with items, but felt that 2 answers was enough. You could post any of those.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate

A comment mentions aggregation; actually, 'aggregate' might work.

You could say aggregates - these are the parts that make up a whole.

And in your example:

I put the items in the two boxes together, they were aggregates in the process of being combined (to form a single, new collection of objects.)

The consolidator has consolidated aggregates.

Or the aggregator has aggregated aggregates.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/thesaurus/aggregate